# How do I parse and access JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript

When I did

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data);
```

I got

```
{"deviceId":"1234","instanceId":"drogon","operationalEvent":"Shutdown","subEventReason":"Finished","operationalState":"in shutdown","createdAt":"2019-06-07 15:22:17","initiator":"system"}
```

When I did

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data.deviceId);
```

I got

```
app.js:10254 undefined
```

What did I do wrong ?

---

## Updated - more info

```
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))) //object
```

---

```
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data) //string
```

Comment: What does the original value `e` look like? What about `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data)`?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve by serializing something and then immediately deserializing it? (That is, calling `JSON.parse()` on the result of `JSON.stringify()` immediately.)

Comment: Stab into the dark: `e.data` is a JSON string, and you need to `JSON.decode` *it*…!?

Comment: `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data) //string`

Comment: It returns string, guys.

Comment: Yeah, so `JSON.parse(e.data)`.

Comment: Well there you go.  It's going to be hard to provide much more guidance without seeing what `e` looks like originally and without some explanation for the context for doing what you're doing.

Comment: `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))) //object`

Comment: @Pointy I added more result of console.log base on what you asked in the post.

Comment: @kyo thanks, but still (1) it would be nice to see what `e` is before that code and (2) it would be helpful to understand what it is that you want your code to do

Comment: @kyo 
May be you are over complicating it. You might want to try this

    E = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data;
    console.log(E.deviceId);

This would display the deviceId. Where e is the JSON object.

Comment: @Bhagirath That's exactly what OP is already doing…!?

Comment: @deceze, with all due respect, OP is unparsing an already parsed object and trying to fetch an object out of a string. Hence, the error.
Here i've tried this -> 
https://jsfiddle.net/ppuneeth63/p19e2c3m/1/

Comment: I am thoroughly astounded by the blindness as to the uselessness of a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))` in this thread and will not further discuss it… ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))` is nonsense, it's the same as just the original object `e` to begin with. Since you say that `e.data` is a string, that's what you need to parse:

```
let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
console.log(data.deviceId);
```

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)) != e  example: try `e = { a: undefined }`

Comment: Not quite; any functions previously attached to `e` would be lost, and circular references would cause an error.

Comment: Yes, okay, there are slight differences, not to mention that you're copying the object yada yada. As far as decoding data is concerned, it serves no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let e= { data: `{"deviceId":"1234","instanceId":"drogon","operationalEvent":"Shutdown","subEventReason":"Finished","operationalState":"in shutdown","createdAt":"2019-06-07 15:22:17","initiator":"system"}` }

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data).deviceId);
```

Comment: VM213:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: snippet works in my browser after push blue "Run..." button (without error) - this means that you have broken computer :)

Comment: There's no point in JSON.anything to begin with here. This is not the situation OP is actually dealing with.

Comment: `code.replace('JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))', 'e')`…

Comment: You first stringify it to a string, which you then immediately parse again! It's entirely pointless! *(whatever) → JSON string → (whatever)*

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)) is not non-sense as pointe above. It is used to remove object reference.
You can try this

```
const data1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)).data
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data1) // e.data is of type 'string' as you have pointed out
const deviceId = parsedData.deviceId
```

Comment: It is very much nonsense in the context of trying to parse `e.data` as JSON…

Comment: @deceze Not necessarily. It creates a shallow clone of the object. This way, if the object is mutated later, it won't mutate the original object.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Sure, but that’s absolutely beside the question here. The goal is to parse `e.data`.